# Insert text in to Input Field using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert text in to an input field using [this code](http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/).

This is the code I am using:

```
<input class="cid" type="text" name="c1" />
<input class="cid" type="text" name="c2" />
<input type="button" value="Insert Text" onclick="insertAtCaret('c1','TEXTTOINSERT1');insertAtCaret('c2','TEXTTOINSERT2');" />
```

But nothing is happening.
I don't know JS so I'm not sure if the JS code I referenced before is only for textareas  which did work when I tested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the link uses the ID of the element, so you'll have to add an ID :

```
<input class="cid" type="text" name="c1" id="c1" />
<input type="button" value="Insert Text" onclick="insertAtCaret('c1','TEXTTOINSERT');" />
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eVVqd/)